# PHP didnt select a correct value from while loop

Tags: php, html

I have a problem regarding while loop. I have a option tag and hidden value inside the loop, the option tag work correctly for the dropdown list but the hidden value is not match with the selected dropdown list.

This is my code :

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'config.php';
$option1 = '';
$idseason='';
$season = '';

$query1 = "select id,description from codemaster_local where codeclass = 'season' and description like '%1st%' group by description";
$result1 = mysqli_query($doa,$query1);
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
$option1 .= "<option value='".$row1['description']."'>".$row1['description']."</option>";
$hidden = "<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row1['id']."'>";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $season = $_POST['season'];
 $idseason = $_POST['id'];

 echo "Season :"; echo $season;echo "<br>";
 echo "ID : ";echo $idseason;
    }
?>

<html>  
      <head>  
           <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
           <link href="style/sty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
           <link href="style/dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>  
      <body>  
          <form class="form-style-9" action="" method="post">
            <table>

                <tr><td><b>Season:</b></td>
                    <td> <select name="season" class="select-css">
                         <?php  echo $option1; ?>
                        </select>      
                        <?php  echo $hidden; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit"> 
          </form>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

[image]

[image]

For example, the id for 1st season 2005 should be 24800 but instead it choose the last id 30539. I select any of the season also still choose the last id. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`$hidden` is being overwritten upon every loop within your while.  Resulting in one hidden field with the name: id, containing the value of the last row id retrieved.  That is the value you receive upon submission.

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $option1 .= "<option value='".$row1['description']."'>".$row1['description']."</option>";
    $hidden = "<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row1['id']."'>";
}
```

I suggest you change the `option`'s value attribute to `$row1['id']`:

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $option1 .= "<option value='".$row1['id']."'>".$row1['description']."</option>";
}
```

This way, `$_POST['season']` will then hold the corresponding id for the season selected.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but later i need to insert season and id into the table. Thats why i put the hidden field. Is there other way to hold the id along with the season?

Comment: with this you only need to insert the ID into a table, when retrieving your data in the future, you would then do a JOIN query.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the id in the option tag instead of a hidden tag:

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $option1 .= "<option value='".$row1['description']."' id='".$row1['id']."'>".$row1['description']."</option>";
}
```

Comment: ids are not passed through by default upon HTML form submission.  It's easier here for the option's value to hold the corresponding id/key.